# identificar quando a página e aberta em uma popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

É possível identificar se a página foi aberta em uma pop-up?

Quero fazer isso com javascript ou jquery.

Tenho a página teste.html, e se ele for aberta em uma pop-up preciso que apareça um link para fechamento 'fechar'

Tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WINDOW.OPENER**

Ao abrir uma página utilizando técnicas como `window.open`, a variável `Window.opener` é alimentada com as informações da página que gerou a requisição. Caso a página não tenha sido aberta dessa forma, retorna `NULL`:

```js
if (window.opener) { // Window.opener recebe os dados da página que gerou a atual
    document.getElementById("fechar").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#fechar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="fechar">FECHAR</a>

<p>Essa é sua Página.</p>
```